# Convert JSON value in SQL table to multiple columns

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

One of my SQL table has two columns in the below format. Column "Parameters" in JSON Format

| Value | Parameters |
| --- | --- |
| 999-99-9999 | {"A":null,"B":"dfsnl","C":"dfdfs","D":"dsfdfs","E":"","F":"dfssdfsdfdsf", "G":null,"H":"dfdsf,dfssfddfsdsffds","I":"73834874378","J":null,"K":null} |

I am wondering if the column Parameter could be split into multiple column and hoping to achieve below format

| Value | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 999-99-9999 |  | dfsnl | dfdfs | dfdfs |  | dfssdfsdfdsf |  | dfdsf,dfssfddfsdsffds | 73834874378 |  |  |

Below query does not seem to work for me. Help please?

```
SELECT t.Value , t.Parameters       , P.*
from MYTABLE t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Parameters) 
WITH (
A varchar(10),
B varchar(10),
C varchar(10),
D varchar(10),
E varchar(10),
F varchar(10),
G varchar(10),
H varchar(10),
I varchar(10),
J varchar(10),
K varchar(10)
) P;
```

Comment: Do you want to do this in a query? Or do you want to alter the table? And which database and version, please?

Comment: I want to split the column Parameters into different column.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio 15.0.18390.0

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016

Comment: Do you want to do this split permanently or for a single query?

Comment: Are you not scrolling far enough over? Try removing `Parameters` from your select list (or shifting it to the end). [Seems to be the result you're after](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7d9fde5af68d966b5e6107081fea7044), no? Maybe we need a better description than "does not seem to work for me."

Answer (score 2):

Use [`openjson`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/convert-json-data-to-rows-and-columns-with-openjson-sql-server?view=sql-server-2016#option-2---openjson-output-with-an-explicit-structure) to turn the JSON into a set of rows and columns. By default this will make a row for each key/value pair. If you want one row with named columns, use `with` and give it a schema and JSON queries for each column.

`cross apply` it with the table to combine the JSON columns with real columns.

```
SELECT value, a, b, c
FROM test
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (parameters) with(
  a nvarchar(255) '$.A', b nvarchar(255) '$.B', c nvarchar(255) '$.C'
)
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d4dd35f3fb8f72ee5a509316c59a5774).

See [examples 3 and 4 in the `openjson` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016#example-3---join-rows-with-json-data-stored-in-table-cells-using-cross-apply) and [JSON Data in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2016) for more.

Comment: @NIVEA Note that the path `'$.A` is not actually necessary unless you are using a different name (or changing to uppercase like here)